# How do I align ul popover class with my respective sections?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a popover class of respective sections, but it is not aligning as symmetrically as desired.

I want it to look like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/DrbkBj36M

Here is my CSS/HTML. Help would be much appreciated.

```css
.filters {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: right;
    min-height: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.locations {
  border-right: #DDDDDD solid 1px;
}

.locations, .amenities {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: .6;
}

h4 {
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: .6;
}

button {
  border:none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #FF5A5F;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 30px 0 auto;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.popover {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color:#FAFAFA;
  border: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 30px 30px 30px;
  margin: 0;
}


.locations:hover .popover {
  display: block;
}

.amenities:hover .popover {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="4-common.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="6-filters.css" media="all">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <section class="filters">
      <div class="locations">
        <h3>States</h3>
        <h4>California, New York...</h4>
        <ul class="popover">
          <h2>California</h2>
            <li>Berkeley</li>
            <li>Los Angeles</li>
            <li>San Francisco</li>
          <h2>New York</h2>
          <li>New York</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="amenities">
        <h3>Amenities</h3>
        <h4>Internet, kitchen...</h4>
        <ul class="popover">
          <h2>Amenities</h2>
          <li>Fiber internets</li>
          <li>Big stove</li>
          <li>Cryogenic chamber</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button>Search</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh.. is this what you want?

```css
.filters {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: right;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.locations {
  border-right: #DDDDDD solid 1px;
}

.locations, .amenities {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: .6;
}

h4 {
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: .6;
}

button {
  border:none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #FF5A5F;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 30px 0 auto;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color:#FAFAFA;
  border: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 30px 30px 30px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.amenities .popover
{
    margin-left: -2px;
}


.locations:hover .popover {
  display: block;
}

.amenities:hover .popover {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="4-common.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="6-filters.css" media="all">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <section class="filters">
      <div class="locations">
        <h3>States</h3>
        <h4>California, New York...</h4>
        <ul class="popover">
          <h2>California</h2>
            <li>Berkeley</li>
            <li>Los Angeles</li>
            <li>San Francisco</li>
          <h2>New York</h2>
          <li>New York</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="amenities">
        <h3>Amenities</h3>
        <h4>Internet, kitchen...</h4>
        <ul class="popover">
          <h2>Amenities</h2>
          <li>Fiber internets</li>
          <li>Big stove</li>
          <li>Cryogenic chamber</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button>Search</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoa! Awesome. Almost there @user6003859. I want to get the popover to align with the outer edge of the whole div, and move it all under, so it looks like an expansion of the respective "States" and "Amenities" divs.

Comment: Well.. howbow dah

Comment: Super super close @user6003859. Gotta figure out how to align "Amenities" with the dividing line and move both down like one pixel.

Comment: One pixel down and aligned with the Amenities line. Done.

Comment: You make the internets a better place @user6003859. Thank you so much! Royalty amongst royalty! I just tried upvoting your answer, but SO won't let me yet (you have to have a reputation of 15, but it was recorded by SO).

Comment: Another question @user6003859: how would I get that dividing line to extend out to completely to the edges? https://www.screencast.com/t/urN1ukp1gCM8

Comment: Like so? Also, I think you're supposed to accept an answer, and then submit a new question if you have one.

Comment: Just like so! Thank you @user6003859, and will submit a new question moving forward.